# Is there an ExecutorService that creates a new thread for every task?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I need to unit-test some functionality that works across threads, for which I need to guarantee that two jobs are run on different threads.

Using `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` introduces a race-condition, because the test may or may not use the cached thread-pool.

Is there an `ExecutorService` that always uses a new thread?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a [`java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with a `corePoolSize` of `0` and a `keepAliveTime` of `0`. This will make new tasks spawn a new thread, and threads will be killed immediately after tasks are terminated.

For example:

```
final ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
    0, 2, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>());

executorService.submit(task1);
executorService.submit(task2);
```

Comment: Caveat: (IIUC) if tasks are queued then those _will_ reuse existing threads once they become available. Put another way: a thread is killed after task completion only if no other tasks are available for immediate execution.

Answer (score 3):

As of JDK 19 (preview) you can use [`Executors.newThreadPerTaskExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newThreadPerTaskExecutor(java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)).